# Corrupt CR2\JPEG file - correct size but all zeros in Hex editor

Tags: jpeg, hexadecimal

I have an SD card with some RAW images (.CR2) and JPEG's that show the correct size but won't open (invalid image). Hex editor shows all zeros in these files.

Before you answer the obvious "All zeros = no data = no way to repair it"...

consider another scenario where I actually HAD success where a file was showing 0KB but after doing a CHKDSK, I was able to successfully restore the file's data from the .CHK file the CHKDSK created. So although an all 0 hex file might seem like "no data", maybe someone has had some luck with this in getting the data back? (maybe the data is stored somewhere?) I am now running data restoration programs and will update if they restore something.

Note: I did a CHKDSK on the SD card but there are no errors.

Comment: I assume you copied the files off of the SD card before you opened them with a hex editor?

Comment: Yes, I always first create a sector-by-sector image AND copy any existing files from a disk that needs recovery, before I do anything else. I checked the hex from the copied file - not from the SD card itself.

Comment: data recovery on sd cards is difficult at best, sorry i cannot help with that. You should re write your question and tags to reflect you wish to perform data recovery on a SD card.

Comment: Sorry for only saying something 1 year later. That was when I found this. You most likely had a fake SD card. Yes, those exist. When you write, the writting may succeed, but the firmware in the card is hacked in such a way that it starts returning junk after you read/write beyound a certain point. You can try http://superuser.com/questions/631633/how-to-tell-if-you-have-a-fake-sd-card to see if it is a fake card.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell if you have a fake sd card](https://superuser.com/questions/631633/how-to-tell-if-you-have-a-fake-sd-card)

Comment: I don't know why we are dealing with a question from 2015 but it's not a duplicate of the 2013 question because there it's talking about a fake card that is showing fake size and corrupting files as you write to the card. My card is not fake and has no writing issues - only issues with existing corrupted files.

Comment: "Before you answer the obvious "All zeros = no data = no way to repair it"...

consider another scenario where I actually HAD success where a file was showing 0KB but after doing a CHKDSK"

Totally different scenarios.