# microSD card doesn't preserve data and format

Tags: usb-flash-drive, sd-card, 7-zip

I recently bought a new 512GB Toshiba PRO Plus microSD card, SDXC card, to be used with a USB type-A adapter on `Ubuntu` or `SolusOS` (linux distro) primarily and to take backups of some `7zip` encrypted and compressed archives, some pictures and videos.

On Linux distros, it only gets formatted to `exFAT`. If I try to format it to `ext3` or `ext4` on Disks app, (preferably with LUKS encryption) then it gives an error. On GParted, it keeps on giving various recommendations to create partitions or partitions maps or logical partitions but doesn't give me a whole card single formatted ext3 or ext4 disk.

If I format it to exFAT and from SolusOS (or from macOS) I copy 7zip encrypted archives, photos (jpegs, pngs) and videos (mov, mp4) then photos on microSD card remain accessible but the 7zip encrypted archives and video files get corrupted on the microSD SDXC card.

Is it a general behaviour of microSD card with high capacity or am I doing something terribly wrong with my usage of microSD card?

Comment: It sounds more like it's a fake card, not as large as advertised. You can sometimes guess just by price - 10 bucks fake, 50 or more real. Send it back.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell if you have a fake sd card](https://superuser.com/questions/631633/how-to-tell-if-you-have-a-fake-sd-card)

Comment: “512GB Toshiba PRO Plus microSD card” How much did you pay for it? Return it for a full refund; it’s a fake or defective card. I would not trust the seller you purchased this item from. There is no magical way to use a high capacity SD card. It’s simply storage. But everything you describe points to it being fake.

Comment: I paid almost $50 for this microSD card and I purchased it 2-months ago from the most popular e-Commerce store of my adopted country. Legally, I can send back a faulty product within 14-days for a full refund in this country but in this case I may have to process RMA with Toshiba or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

Check some of the corrupt files using a hex editor (HxD is free) and see if they're largely filled with zeros or repeating byte pattern like xFF xFF xFF xFF xFF  etc..

Some people are intimidated by a hex editor, but there's no reason for that. Simply run it and open one of the corrupt files just like you'd do in any other Windows program.

[image]

If so then this is a fake card, in the sense that firmware is modified to show larger capacity than actual NAND memory present (typically only 8 - 16 - 32 GB).

The firmware is modified so it will not report errors when reading or writing from non existing NAND. The exFAT file system for which file system meta data is stored towards the start of the volume can update the file allocation tables, and update for example the ROOT as if nothing is wrong.

So then it is possible to create a file for which file system meta data is correct but the clusters allocated to the file are entirely in non existing NAND memory. If one reads these clusters the firmware simply returns sectors filled with zeros or other byte value like xFF.